# loading model template from separate html file in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a model in angularJS with angular UI, and I tried to use this code in my page's controller

```
$scope.insertEvent = function() {
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'views/overlays/insert-event.html'
        });
    };
```

Inside insert-event.html it looks like this:

```
<section class="overlay overlay-insert-event">
    <span class="bg"></span>
    <form class="wrap">
        <header>
            Insert an Event
        </header>

        <div class="main">
            <label>Name<input type="text" ng-model="newEvent.name" name="name" /></label>
            <label>Start<input type="text" date-picker ng-model="newEvent.start" name="start" /></label>
            <label>Stop<input type="text" date-picker ng-model="newEvent.stop" name="stop" /></label>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <button ng-click="insertEventSubmit()">Insert</button>
            <a ng-click="insertEventReset()">Cancel</a>
        </footer>
    </form>
</section>
```

Now the problem is that when I open it, the background of the overlay with the semi-tranparent black appears, but the content doesn't appear. I hope someone can help me understand how this works. Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: I did something like this.

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: URl + 'public/js/templates/profile/convert-to-prof.html',
                backdrop: 'static',
                scope: $scope,
                windowClass: 'crz-convert-modal'
                }
            });

Answer (score 0):

Where is your views folder located? Try '/views/overlays/insert-event.html' if it is directly located under the project.

Comment: i tried that and now nothing appears, not even the semi-transparent background

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the HTML for your modal content in proper HTML tags with an ng-app directive defined. Worked for me when I also got just the background overlay when opening the modal.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Modal
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="yourAppName">
      <<<YOUR_CONTENT>>>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```